# I don't manage to change background color of a menu element on a specific page on WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm currently working on a website based on WordPress (not the funniest thing I know). I want to be able to change the background color in the CSS properties of the menu part where the user is on the website. I used for that the page-id and then specify children and children of the children to go deeper until I reached the li element I'm targeting. Not working...
SO if you know any other technique or if you see an error in my way of doing it, I will be pleased if you can tell me.

this is the html, I put in bold the id elements which are targeted in the CSS code below

```
        <body class="page-template page-template-elementor_header_footer page **page-id-939** wp-custom-logo wp-embed-responsive oceanwp-theme dropdown-mobile has-transparent-header default-breakpoint has-sidebar content-right-sidebar page-header-disabled has-breadcrumbs pagination-center elementor-default elementor-template-full-width elementor-kit-354 elementor-page elementor-page-939" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage">
    
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-dark-grayscale"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 0.49803921568627" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.49803921568627" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 0.49803921568627" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-grayscale"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-purple-yellow"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.54901960784314 0.98823529411765" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.71764705882353 0.25490196078431" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-blue-red"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.27843137254902" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.5921568627451 0.27843137254902" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-midnight"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 0" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.64705882352941" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-magenta-yellow"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.78039215686275 1" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.94901960784314" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.35294117647059 0.47058823529412" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-purple-green"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.65098039215686 0.40392156862745" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.44705882352941 0.4" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-blue-orange"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.098039215686275 1" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.66274509803922" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.84705882352941 0.41960784313725" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg>
        
        <div id="**outer-wrap**" class="site clr">
    
            <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#main">Skip to content</a>
    
            
            <div id="**wrap**" class="clr">
    
                
                    <div id="**transparent-header-wrap**" class="clr">
        
    <header id="**site-header**" class="transparent-header has-social clr" data-height="74" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/WPHeader" role="banner">
    
        
                        
                <div id="**site-header-inner**" class="clr container">
    
                    
                    
    
    <div id="site-logo" class="clr" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Brand" >
    
        
        <div id="site-logo-inner" class="clr">
    
            <a href="https://beta.in-viva.net/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home"><img width="140" height="103" src="https://beta.in-viva.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/cropped-in_Viva_logo_noir-722x1024-1-e1642607586360.png" class="custom-logo" alt="in-viva" srcset="https://beta.in-viva.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/cropped-in_Viva_logo_noir-722x1024-1-e1642607586360.png 1x, https://beta.in-viva.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/cropped-in_Viva_logo_noir-722x1024-1-e1642607586360.png 2x" /></a>
        </div><!-- #site-logo-inner -->
    
        
        
    </div><!-- #site-logo -->
    
    
    
    
    <div class="oceanwp-social-menu clr simple-social">
    
        <div class="social-menu-inner clr">
    
            
                <ul aria-label="Social links">
    
                    <li class="oceanwp-twitter"><a href="#" aria-label="Twitter (opens in a new tab)" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class=" fab fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true" role="img"></i></a></li><li class="oceanwp-facebook"><a href="#" aria-label="Facebook (opens in a new tab)" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class=" fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" role="img"></i></a></li><li class="oceanwp-instagram"><a href="#" aria-label="Instagram (opens in a new tab)" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class=" fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true" role="img"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
    
            
        </div>
    
    </div>
                <div id="**site-navigation-wrap**" class="clr">
                
                
                
                <nav id="**site-navigation**" class="navigation main-navigation clr" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" role="navigation" >
    
                    <ul id="**menu-main-menu**" class="main-menu dropdown-menu sf-menu"><li id="**menu-item-522**" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-522"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/ambition" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Ambition</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-523" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-523"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/impact" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Impact</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-524" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-524"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/references" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Références</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-525" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-525"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/offre" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Offre</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-526" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-526"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/equipe" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Equipe</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-527" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-527"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/methodologie" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Méthodologie</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-528" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-528"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/approche-et-outils" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Approche et Outils</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-530" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-530"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/contact" class="menu-link"><span class="text-wrap">Contact</span></a></li></ul>
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    
                
                
                        </div><!-- #site-navigation-wrap -->
                
            
        
                    
        
        <div class="oceanwp-mobile-menu-icon clr mobile-right">
    
            
            
            
            <a href="#" class="mobile-menu"  aria-label="Menu mobile">
                                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <span class="oceanwp-text">Menu</span>
                    <span class="oceanwp-close-text">Fermer</span>
                            </a>
    
            
            
            
        </div><!-- #oceanwp-mobile-menu-navbar -->
    
        
    
                </div><!-- #site-header-inner -->
    
                
    <div id="mobile-dropdown" class="clr" >
    
        <nav class="clr has-social" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    
            <ul id="menu-main-menu-1" class="menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-522"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/ambition">Ambition</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-523"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/impact">Impact</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-524"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/references">Références</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-525"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/offre">Offre</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-526"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/equipe">Equipe</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-527"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/methodologie">Méthodologie</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-528"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/approche-et-outils">Approche et Outils</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-530"><a href="https://www.beta.in-viva.net/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And this is my CSS code which comes from the page id and go deeper until the li element I target

```
        /* ambition */
    #page-id-939 #outer-wrap #wrap #transparent-header-wrap #site-header #site-header-inner #site-navigation-wrap #site-navigation #menu-main-menu #menu-item-522 {
        background-color: black !important;
        color: #E0CDA9 !important;
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to share the website you are working on so I could have a look properly?

You're doing a good job, I perhaps advise maybe learning to use css classes more in the future rather than nesting id tags in css. It will just help in the long run for better class specificity. [Here is a good read on that][1]. 


  [1]: https://dev.to/clairecodes/reasons-not-to-use-ids-in-css-4ni4

Comment: Thanks for answering ;)
It's wordpress wich make the id, i usually work with class when it s my own code except for really specifics elements
The website is :
http://www.beta.in-viva.net

Comment: So you want to change the beige background colour of the header?

Comment: No, i already change the background color, i want for example if someone goes into the Ambition page, the background of Ambition in the menu (and only this part) to change background color. For that i think i have to specify the page ID so it happen s only when the user is on the specific targeted page
The reason is to help user understand in every-time in wich section of the website they are by having a visual indicator of the section they are in by having this part in the menu a different background color

Answer (score 1):

Okay so to change the background colour to a certain page in Wordpress via it's page-id. You would do the following.

```
body.page-id-939 #site-header.transparent-header {
    background: red !important;
}
```

So I'm targeting the body with it's class of `page-id-939` for the page ambition. Then we can nest in the `#site-header.transparent-header`